# how to apply sorting and filtering to an one-row dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, subset, rowwise

I have a special data frame with only one row. I would like to sort it in ascending order and filter out columns which is smaller than a critical value. Here is an example:

```
a1 <- c("1")
a2 <- c("3")
a3 <- c("2")
a4 <- c("0")
b <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4)
```

Here is what the data frame looks like, and this is what I have from other code.

```
  a1 a2 a3 a4
1  1  3  2  0
```

Say the critical value is 2.5, then the expected output is:

```
  a4 a1 a3
1  0  1  2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `b[order(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(b))))]` Not clear why you are creating `factor/character` by quoting

Comment: ```b[,b[1,] < 2.5][,order(b[,b[1,] < 2.5])]```

Comment: `b <- type.convert(b, as.is = TRUE); sort(b[,b < 2.5])`

Comment: Thanks you all! Yes, I should not use the quoting.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sort` and `Filter`

```
sort(Filter(function(x) x < 2.5, b))
#  a4 a1 a3
#1  0  1  2
```

**data**

```
a1 <- 1
a2 <- 3
a3 <- 2
a4 <- 0
b <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4) 
critical_value = 2.5
```